# Control not entering the handler class

Tags: apex, trigger, error, recursion

I have written an after update trigger on the Content Version and I have used a boolean to check recursion

Handler :

```
public Class checkRecursive { 
   private static boolean run = true; 
   public static boolean runOnce() {
      if(run) {
        run=false;
        return true; 
       }else { 
         return run; 
        } 
    }
}
```

trigger :

```
 trigger TriggerOnContentVersion on ContentVersion ( after update,before update) {
     handlerClassContentVersion handler = new handlerClassContentVersion();
     System.debug('eeeeeeeee '+checkRecursive.runOnce());
     if(checkRecursive.runOnce() == TRUE ){
        if((trigger.isupdate && trigger.isAfter) ||test.isrunningtest()){ 
            handler.onAfterInsert(trigger.new,trigger.oldMap);
        }  
     }
}
```

The Debug is showing the value as `true` for the first time and  `false` the next time but it is still not entering the loop

Comment: can you share your complete trigger also some handler code

Comment: I have updated the question. And in my handler class, I just have a debug to check if it is being printed.

`public Class checkRecursive{

    private static boolean run = true;

    public static boolean runOnce(){

    if(run){

     run=false;

     return true;

    }else{

        return run;
    }
    }
}`

That's my recursion handling class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two issue in your code. Not sure which one is the main issue.

1. first your trigger run in before update and set the return true. but your if condition `Trigger.isAfter` not allow to enter it on controller and call the method. second time your trigger run in after trigger and runs is already false. so it don't allow again.
2. Second is method called  from debug(not sure if you use this in actual code as well) and set run to false and return true. now from your method `if(checkRecursive.runOnce() == TRUE )` it return false because due to debug call it is set to false..

Check these two condition and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I didn't understand the second issue. Could you please explain?

Comment: @User2529 Check updated answer.